вылазит консоль powershell когда скомпилировал програму без консоли на python

Имеется проблема в виде того что когда компилирую свой код командой pyinstaller -c -F -w -i ico.ico -n test main.py то вылазит консоль powershell в момент когда исполняется команда powershell в коде, если скомпилировать код без приписки -w тобиж с консолью то таких проблем нет. Вопрос что делать? Мне нужно что бы программа работала без консоли и можно было отправлять powershell команды в программе без такого прикола. Вот код:
import time
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import subprocess


class Ada(QThread):
    message = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            cstatp = subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', r'Get-NetAdapter'],capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
            print(cstatp)
            time.sleep(2)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35)')

        self.setMaximumSize(1280, 720)
        self.setMinimumSize(1280, 720)
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(':/cf/ico.png'))

        self.t1 = Ada()
        self.t1.message.connect(self.set)
        self.t1.start()


    def set(self, v):
        self.aa.setText(v)

import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Main()
w.resize(1280, 720)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


Укажите атрибут -WindowStyle Hidden для powershell:
cstatp = subprocess.run(['powershell.exe', r'-WindowStyle', r'Hidden', r'Get-NetAdapter'], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout

